# FreeMM vs ShareMem

Tags: delphi, memory-management, fastmm

We have a lot of dll-libraries written in both delphi and c++ builder, and use sharemem and borlndmm.dll.

An aligment-issue in a 3thparty library forces us over to the new memorymanager in delphi 2007.

Can someone please explain 'shared memory manager' for me?
Is SimpleShareMem a dropin replacement for ShareMem ?
Can we then stop deploying borlndmm.dll?
Do we have to do something with the c++-libraries as well?
Can some libraries use ShareMem and some SimpleShareMem?

Thanks,
-Vegar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the answer to most of my questions in this thread: [borland.public.delphi.language.basm](http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.language.basm/browse_frm/thread/8b70a36f331f137e?ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=Re:+FastMM+questions):

> Either use
>   (a) SimpleShareMem.pas/FastMM4.pas, or use
>   (b) ShareMem.pas (i.e. borlndmm.dll)
>   You cannot mix the two different sharing methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?threadID=6608 for an interesting discussion about this subject.

Comment: (your link not clickable - or it is, but..)