# Writing Delphi/FreePascal DLL to be called from gcc application

Tags: delphi, dll, gcc, freepascal, shared-libraries

I need to make parts of my Win32 Delphi app available to another company's Linux gcc program.

Throughput and deployment requirements make any sort of remote service unsuitable so I'm looking at using FreePascal to build a .SO (Linux equivalent of a DLL) that the gcc app can call.

It's a long time since I used C/C++ and never on Linux so I'm a little unsure as to how best to structure the DLL/SO interface for compatibility with a gcc caller.

Here's a representation of my data structures

```
TFoo = record
  x, y : double;
  a : smallint;
  b : string;
end;

TBar = record
  a : double;
  b : longint;
  c : string;
end;

TFooBar = record
  foo : array of TFoo;
  bar : array of TBar;
end;

procedure Process(const inFooBar : TFooBar);
```

To make this Process method externally available via a FreePascal .SO how do I need to modify these declarations? I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
TFoo = record
  x, y : double;
  a : smallint;
  b : PChar;
end;

TBar = record
  a : double;
  b : longint;
  c : PChar;
end;

TFooBar = record
  foo : ^TFoo;
  foo_count : longint;
  bar : ^TBar;
  bar_count : longint;
end;

procedure Process(const inFooBar : TFooBar);
```

Am I on the right track? I don't have to get this exactly right, the other company's programmers will very likely fix up my mistakes. I just don't want them to laugh too hard when they see what I've sent them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `PAnsiChar` instead of `PChar`, and `integer` instead of `longint/smallint` (since you use aligned records, there is no benefit of using a smallint field).

Define some pointer types like `PFoo` and `PBar`, which will be better written than `^TFoo` e.g.

If you need to access some arrays, you could define `TFooArray` and `TBarArray`, as in the code below.

Don't forget the `cdecl` or `stdcall` calling convention for any function/procedure.

```
type
TFoo = record
  x, y : double;
  a : integer;
  b : PAnsiChar;
end;

TBar = record
  a : double;
  b : integer;
  c : PAnsiChar;
end;

TFooArray = array[0..maxInt div sizeof(TFoo)-1] of TFoo;
TBarArray = array[0..maxInt div sizeof(TBar)-1] of TBar;

PBar = ^TBar;
PFoo = ^TFoo;
PFooArray = ^TFooArray;
PBarArray = ^TBarArray;

TFooBar = record
  foo : PFooArray;
  foo_count : integer;
  bar : PBarArray;
  bar_count : integer;
end;

procedure Process(const inFooBar : TFooBar); cdecl; external 'ProcessGCCLibrary.so';
```

Will be your process read-only?

If the C part need to add some items, you'll have to provide some memory reallocation methods to the external library, mapping at least `reallocmem()`.

Note that Delphi dynamic arrays can be mapped easily into C compatible structure, as such:

```
type
  TFooDynArray: array of TFoo;
  TBarDynArray: array of TBar;

procedure CallProcess(const aFoo: TFooDynArray; const aBar: TBarDynArray);
var tmp: TFooBar;
begin
  tmp.foo := pointer(aFoo);
  tmp.foo_count := length(aFoo);
  tmp.bar := pointer(aBar);
  tmp.bar_count := length(aBar);
  Process(tmp);
end;
```

This could make your Delphi code much more readable. Take a look at our [`TDynArray` wrapper](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/12/TDynArray-and-Record-compare/load/save-using-fast-RTTI) if you want high-level access to such a dynamic array of records, with `TList`-like methods.

Since the `AnsiString` type maps a `PAnsiChar`, from the binary point of view, you can even define your records as such:

```
type
TFoo = record
  x, y : double;
  a : integer;
  b : AnsiString;
end;

TBar = record
  a : double;
  b : integer;
  c : AnsiString;
end;
```

When mapped to the gcc application, it will be read as a regular `*char`.

Using `AnsiString` here you won't need to handle memory allocation from your Delphi code. With an associated dynamic array, it could make your Delphi code much easier to maintain. Note that our `TDynArray` wrapper will handle nested `AnsiString` in records as expected, even for the highest level methods (e.g. binary serialization or hashing).

Comment: Thanks for such a very detailed answer. I'm going to be compiling using FreePascal rather than Delphi though, do you know if your advice on AnsiString and dynamic arrays applies equally for FreePascal too?

Comment: @LachlanG Yes, the dynamic array and string implementation are the same for FPC and Delphi. So you can use my proposal for both. In FPC you've only AnsiString (i.e. string=AnsiString as in earlier Delphi versions).

Comment: @ A. Bouchez: Your use of `AnsiString` is **dangerous**.  Sure `AnsiString`s are null-terminated, so can be cast to `PAnsiChar`s, except that they also have a reference count at a negative offset - ie if data is passed to the DLL using your recommended structure and the pointer is interpreted in Delphi code as a genuine `AnsiString`, it could cause a lot of trouble. Safer to make a `PAnsiChar` that and only that. (Also, why ANSI?  It's 2011.  Make it a Unicode string.) A good general guideline is that managed types, like strings, should not cross language or DLL/EXE boundaries.

Comment: @David Just take a look at the internals of the RTL. This use is **not dangerous at all** if the dll only **read** the `*char` array. For writing the buffer, you'll need a custom `reallocmem` to call from C, as I wrote. That was my point. This is perfectly safe, and even **the VCL do this all the time** when calling the Windows API. And why use Ansi? Just because FPC under Linux (which is the targetted compiler by the OP) only handle this kind of string. And Linux is not UCS2 based, but UTF-32 AFAIK. You can safely use UTF-8 encoding, as most Linux libraries do.

Comment: @A. Bouchez: "if the DLL only read the *char array" is my point, which perhaps I didn't express very well.  Suppose it passes a structure to be written into to, for example?  I can only repeat that as a general guideline, managed types like strings should not cross this sort of boundary.  (It also avoids the string reference counting, so you can imagine plausible scenarios where the string is freed on one side and the "string" on the other is no longer valid.)

Comment: @A. Bouchez: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178868/is-it-safe-to-pass-delphi-const-string-params-across-memory-manager-boundaries and http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pchars.html for more information.

Comment: @David The pre-supposal of OP and in my answer was that the structure was passed to be **read**, not written into. If the `*char` content is needed after the external function call, the function should make a private copy. It's perfectly safe to use the `*char` content during all time of the function call. `pointer(aString)` or `PChar(aString)` (the first the faster) are safe when calling an external library (as both links state). It's exactly what the VCL does all the time with Windows API. Your "general guideline" that "managed types should not cross this sort of boundary" is just dogmatic.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the record packing/alignment/padding is as GCC expects, add {$packrecords c} to your Pascal source. Note that this directive is specific to the Free Pascal Compiler, Delphi does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty good.  Thoughts:

- Your arrays (declared as a pointer and count) are going to be fully manually managed - that's fine for you?
- You should change:

  ```
  procedure Process(const inFooBar : TFooBar);
  ```

  to include a C-compatible calling convention.  I'm not sure what FreePascal and GCC both support, but something like `cdecl` should work fine.
- You should also (for safety) specify the structure alignment / packing.
- `PChar` should be explicitly narrow or wide (wide is normal these days.)